# how to spilt the x square in maths equation in rejax

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var equation = $('#equation').val();
        var split = equation.match(/[-+]?\d+[?xy]/g);
        alert(split);
        var matches = equation.match(/-?\b\d+\b/g);
        $('#super').text(split + ',' + matches);
        var ncc = $('#super').text();
        var res = ncc.split(/[,]/g);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="linear.js"></script>
<input type="text" value ="x3+2x2-4y-1=0" id="equation">
<button>solve</button>
<p id="super"></p>
```

how to split the equation in rejax for example `x square(x2)`, `x cube (x3)` in any equation to split the `x` and power value to split.
`x3 + 2x2 - 4y - 1 = 0` in that equation how to split please help me improve this code.

Comment: not sure what you mean, is rejax some sort of library?

Comment: @JaromandaX I think they meant regex ………

Comment: d'oh ... when you say it out loud it's obviarse

Comment: It a regular expression

Comment: please help me to split the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check algebra.js, it's a good library to solve algebraic equations

https://github.com/nicolewhite/algebra.js